# How to change the x axis in a ts object to %Y-%m-%d format from as.numeric

Tags: r, datetime, forecast

I am attempting to implement a forecast based on a time series object. However, when I'm getting graphs out of the code the x-axis is as.numeric version of the date:

[image]

Here's a snapshot of the subset of data used:
[image]

Code used:

```
ts<-ts(temp$total_cases, frequency = 1, start = min(as.Date(temp$date,"%Y-%m-%d")), end = max(as.Date(temp$date,"%Y-%m-%d")))

# time series labeled object for country's dates and
assign(paste0('ts_',country),ts)

fit <- ets(ts_Afghanistan)

plot(forecast(fit))
```

When I enter the following the transition to date of the type of output on the x axis is clear:

```
> as.Date(18300)
[1] "2020-02-08"
```

Just not sure how to get this reflected in the x-axis label. I tried playing with zoo and other functions without success. Would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to override the x-axis. In most base `plot` methods, `xaxt="n"` suppresses the default axis. After that, you `axis` to define a plot. (`axTicks` provides a good set of default tick locations.)

```r
vec <- 18300 + 0:10
plot(vec, vec, xaxt = "n")
axTicks(1)
# [1] 18300 18302 18304 18306 18308 18310
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels = as.character(as.Date(axTicks(1))))
```

[image: basic plot]